# My url rewrites not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

im a first timer when it comes to htaccess files, have been looking trough samples in stackoverflow and not what but nothing seems to work for me, im def a noob doing something wrong.

i got the next url:

[http://www.example.com/index.php?page=page1]

wich i would like to rewrite to be:

[http://www.example.com]

or

[http://www.example.com/page1]

how would i accomplish doing that, can someone give a good simple url rewrite example that would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1 [L]
```

Other than this, read the apache documentation on rewriting urls:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

I know it's dry, and long, and boring, but it's worth it.

Comment: Tnx for responding, i am reading all sorts of docs about htaccess files , uncluding original apache pages ofcourse, but not realy getting the hang of it yet. Anyway that what you've showed me did not work either ... It loads the page but then when u start to click the links the browser says that that link is not existing, like this: "Not Found The requested URL /home was not found on this server."

Comment: To be precise about the real url, altho that shouldnt be a problem i guess, they are: [http://www.capoeiravelsen.nl/index.php?page=home] and i would like to strip the [/index.php?page=home] part from it.

Comment: my htaccess file is: 
RewriteEngine On

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch> 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1 [L]

Comment: First of all, if the page loads, then the rewrite works.

Second, you must keep in mind that the specified rewrite will only work if you specify full file names in the `page` parameter, so `?page=home` expects a file or directory called `home` to exist.

You can avoid this adding e.g. .html to the rewritten url, like
`... /%.html` which will then look for a file called `home.html`.

Comment: ive tried a few combinations but still dont work how would i accomplish what you have mentioned .... tnx :)

Comment: the page loads normally but with your original rewrite rule it doesnt work, i tried this for example: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php inc/%1.php [L]   where inc/ being the folder where inside root folder where all the documents are and fixing a .php behind it. now when i click a link it works but it removes all markup and the menu cannot be seen.